# Updating Entity Associations in Entity Framework 5

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework

I'm currently running into an issue, and I've searched stack overflow high and low with seemingly no solution. I feel like I must be doing something wrong, but hopefully someone can help.

Anyway, I have the following models:

```
public abstract class IDObject
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
}

public class TV : IDObject
{
    public TV()
    {
        this.Channels = new List<Channel>();
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Channel> Channels { get; set; } 
}

public class Channel : IDObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    [Navigational]
    public virtual IList<TV> TVs { get; set; }  
}
```

Tvs - Channels should be a many-many relationship.

Now basically I want to be able to add a TV and a Channel to the database, dispose the context, have the TV reference the channel that has previously been added, then update the database entity.

Something like:

```
TV someTV = new TV() { ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "myBigTV" };
Channel chan1 = new Channel() { ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "CBC", Number = 3};

using (ReferenceContext context = new ReferenceContext())
{
    context.TVs.Add(someTV);
    context.Channels.Add(chan1);
    context.SaveChanges();
}

someTV.Name = "myBigTV updated";
someTV.Channels.Add(chan1);

using (ReferenceContext context = new ReferenceContext())
{
    context.TVs.Attach(someTV);
    context.Entry(someTV).State = EntityState.Modified;
    *** some code here ***
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I do this, my someTV entity is updated, but it still has no refs to Channels when I do a 'find' call in the db.

Now I've tried .Load() on the DbCollectionEntry for Channels. I've tried removing all refs to channels from someTV in the context, then re-adding them. I've tried changing the EntityState on the channels I've referenced from someTV to Modified... and it seems like nothing works.

I'm using code first and the Database is creating the following tables for me:

```
Channels
ChannelTVs
TVs
```

Channels and TVs both look fine, but my join table 'ChannelTVs' is always empty regardless of what I do.

**Question one: What is the standard way to update associations in this scenario. I don't need to necessarily update the Channels themselves, just basically add/remove entities from the join table. Do I need to add something to the fluent API to pick up these changes for me?**

**Question two: Is there any way to do this in a generic way? My current update sort of looks like:**

```
void Update<TDatabase>(IDatabaseContext context, TDatabase item)
{
    IDbSet<TDatabase> dbSet = context.GetDbSet<TDatabase>();
    dbSet.Attach(item);
    context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I know questions like this have been asked before, but it seems like none of the solutions seemed to work. It could be something I'm doing wrong, or maybe just a special case...

Thanks.

Comment: For the purpose of our application, the entity needs to be initially updated outside of the context. The entity is actually updated outside of the application and sent back in through our REST engine and de-serialized via JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone finds this and is curious how... I managed to find a generic solution. Though not pretty, it does work.

```
update()
{
    using (ReferenceContext context = new ReferenceContext())
    {
        TV newTV = context.TVs.Single(x => x.ID == someTV.ID);
        DbEntityEntry entityEntry = context.Entry(newTV);
        entityEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(someTV);
        UpdateReferences(context, entityEntry, someTV);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

private static void UpdateReferences(ReferenceContext context, DbEntityEntry entityEntry, IDObject someObject)
{
    List<PropertyInfo> properties = someObject.GetType().GetProperties().Where(prop => !prop.IsDefined(typeof(NavigationalAttribute), false) && prop.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Any(type => type == typeof(IEnumerable)) && prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().Any()).ToList();

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        IList references = (IList)property.GetValue(someObject, null);
        DbCollectionEntry newCollection = entityEntry.Collection(property.Name);


        var method = typeof(TestEF).GetMethod("Wrapped", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).MakeGenericMethod(property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]);

        method.Invoke(null, new object[] { context, newCollection.CurrentValue, references });
    }
}

private static void Wrapped<T>(ReferenceContext context, IList<T> container, IEnumerable<T> references) where T : IDObject
{
    container.Clear();
    var dbSet = context.GetDbSet<T>();
    foreach (var referencedObject in references)
    {
        T item = dbSet.Find(referencedObject.ID);
        container.Add(item);
    }
}
```